# ISPICKVAL with Custom Label

Tags: formula, picklist, customlabel

I'm trying to use a the ISPICKVAL in a formula with a Custom Label:

```
ISPICKVAL(Type, $Label.Business_Type)
```

I get an error:

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected Text Literal, received Text

It really seems like this should work?! Is there any workaround?

Comment: I'll leave this up as I didn't find any results (SO or Salesforce) when searching for this question.

Answer (score 5):

After some digging I found the (obvious) solution:

```
TEXT(MyPickList_Field__c) == $Label.MyCustomLabel
```